# Executing commands when network goes up or down using dispatcher.d

Tags: bash, scripts, network-manager, network-monitoring, espeak

I'm trying to get the Network Manager dispatcher to run a script when the network interface comes up or goes down. I want to execute an espeak command when the connection goes up or goes down.  ***I can get it to write to the file /tmp/log but I don't hear any sound from the espeak command*** even though I can type it directly on the terminal and it works.

The way I test it is by disconnecting my usb network card (this is the only network card I have in the machine)

I've place the executable file in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`
(it's called **02-ifupdowntest**)

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2293 Mar 26  2018 01-ifupdown
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  534 Jan 23 16:42 02-ifupdowntest
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5383 Mar 27  2018 99tlp-rdw-nm
```

> See contents of **02-ifupdowntest** below:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
if [ "$2" = "up" ]; then

    echo "`date`" > /tmp/log
    echo "$1" >> /tmp/log
    echo "$2" >> /tmp/log
    echo "`/usr/bin/espeak "network up"`"

fi

if [ "$2" = "down" ]; then
    echo "$2" >> /tmp/log
    echo "`/usr/bin/espeak "network down"`"


fi

exit 0
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 64bit Linux

Comment: Your script looks okay. It should work. Do you have `espeak` installed or have you specified the right path?. You can check with `which espeak` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @Raffa yes I can run the command from a command prompt and it works.  It's like it's having problems executing the command but I checked the rights and pasted them above.  I'm at a loss to why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like /etc/network/interfaces overrides the NetworkManager. When I removed the entry from my interface from that file the scripts in dispatcher.d got called properly again.

Comment: What did you remove? and from what interface and from what script?  My script above has nothing like that.

Comment: My /etc/network/interfaces now only contains:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback